# Cannot bind parameter 'headers' for command curl

Tags: curl

I am trying to use curl command with following line below and encountering errors.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name": "ggg","address":"gemany" }'  urlplaceholder
```

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert the "Content-Type: application/json" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary".
At line:1 char:9
+ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name": "ggg"," ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can say you are using Microsoft Power shell utility.. which has different syntax.    It is expecting a hash table type value for headers

```
@{<name> = <value>; [name = <value> ] ...}
```

If you really want it to be working in power shell, please go through power shell's Invoke-WebRequest syntax

When I ran this command in curl, it worked, no issues.

A tweak is if you have git installed in windows, you can set the command prompt to Git\mingw64\bin, and from there execute your curl commands

Answer (score 0):

Using powershell 7 seemed to clear this issue up.